# unserialising array from sql

Tags: php, sql, arrays

having successfully stored my arrays by serializing them, I am having trouble  unserialising amd outputting it back into arrayed data.

```
while( $row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
var_dump($row);

{

$rss=unserialize($row);
echo $rss;
}

var_dump($rss);
```

I have vardumped to try and get a better picture of what is and isnt working and unserialize not working lol..
once the data is unserialised(problem1), I can then send it through a foreach to.output it(problem 2)...?

Comment: What you are doing here --> `while( $row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
var_dump($row);

{` did you not get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$i=0;
while( $row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  foreach($row as $key=>$value)
  {
    $rss[$i][$key]=unserialize($value);
  }
$i++;  
}

var_dump($rss);
```

Comment: get aN error, says.unserialize expecting.string , received array

Comment: ahh, so I have serialized string as value in array... so I need to run through fir each first, then unserislise...?? example would be appreciated

Comment: my original attempt tried this but was unsuccessful

Comment: much much closer...here is a copy of the var dump..I thinkwe need to go one level deeper

Comment: array(8) { ["gamerid"]=> string(1) "g" ["monday"]=> string(50) "a:4:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";i:2;s:1:"7";i:3;s:1:"" ["tuesday"]=> string(2) "N;" ["wednesday"]=> string(2) "N;" ["thursday"]=> string(42) "a:3:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";i:2;s:1:"8";}" ["friday"]=> string(2) "N;" ["saturday"]=> string(50) "a:4:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"4";i:2;s:1:"5";i:3;s:1:"" ["sunday"]=> string(2) "N;" }

Comment: here is the output if your code, minus the interger count

Comment: array(16) { [0]=> array(1) { ["gamerid"]=> bool(false) } [1]=> array(1) { ["monday"]=> bool(false) } [2]=> array(1) { ["tuesday"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(1) { ["wednesday"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(1) { ["thursday"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "8" } } [5]=> array(1) { ["friday"]=> NULL } [6]=> array(1) { ["saturday"]=> bool(false) } [7]=> array(1) { ["sunday"]=> NULL } [8]=> array(1)

Comment: thanks buddy you got this all right.... just a small.adjustment on feild size and all is good.